# Gitlab : Not receive OTP for verify phone number when registering

Tags: gitlab, sms, verification, verify, one-time-password

I’m not receiving any SMS OTP for verifying my phone number when registering for gitlab account. Any solution?

Comment: still till now!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I found on the [forums](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/phone-verification-sms-not-received-unable-to-login-and-register/92202), this is probably a bug of gitlab. I also experienced it.